# Adventure works for SQL server 2014 SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am learning the SSAS and MDXquery for the first time. I am using Sql server 2014 and I am trying to add Adventure works of Data warehouse and Analysis Services.
 I went to https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/105902 but there is no AdeventureWorks  available for Data warehouse 2014 and for Analysis  Services it is also not available https://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=Adventureworks%202014%20%20analysis%20services%20project&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=5.

Is the corrected version of Adventure works released for Data Warehouse and Analysis Service 2014?

Comment: take a look: https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550

Comment: Hi @mcNets the above are for Database Services. I recommend for Analysis Services and Datawarehouse. I have seen below there is Datawarehouse Script but there is no mdf file and no analysis services

Comment: neither Adventure Works 2014 Full Database Backup.zip?

Comment: @mcNets thanks for the link will check the full details

Comment: @mcNets please check the link https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/88252 there is available AdventureWorks 2008R2 Analysis Services Project separarate zip file but it is not available in the above link which you provided and the respective below zip files of 2014 link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the following link download `Adventure Works DW 2014 Full Database Backup.zip` for the DW and `Adventure Works Multidimensional Model SQL 2014 Full Database Backups.zip` for the multidimensional cube.

https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/125550

Answer (score 0):

CodePlex ran through 2006 to 2017 and now is in archive mode till jul 2021. AdventureWorks (2014 and earlier) are [archived on Codeplex for your convenience for downloading](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=msftdbprodsamples).

or can be downloaded from [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks)